# On iOS, how to check inside a new thread for a UISwitch's value in the ViewController's view?

Tags: ios, multithreading

On iOS, if there is a single view app, and a new thread is created using:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(consumeData:) 
     toTarget:self.consumer withObject:self.queue];
```

where the `consumer` is a `Consumer` object that will process data inside the method `consumeData`, and the `queue` is a `Queue` object, which is where the data comes from for the consumer to process.

But what if the thread needs to check whether a Switch on the main view is set to on or off?  That is to toggle whether the `Consumer` object should do the work or pause at the moment.  Should the `withObject:self` be used instead, so that the whole ViewController reference is passed to the thread, and then the thread will use `viewController.view.______` to access the switch's value, and use `viewController.queue` to access the queue, or is there a better or alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not. Nothing UI-related can ever be touched from another thread. It's simply not safe. If the other thread needs to know the switch's current value, then it needs to call back to the main thread before asking for it.

Comment: how to call back to the main thread?  So `ViewController` should implement a `isConsumerSwitchOn` method?

Comment: There's a whole slew of options. In your case, I'd recommend never calling back to the main thread. Instead, maybe put an atomic `bool` property on the consumer and have your thread check that property instead. Then when your switch is flipped, just toggle the property.

Comment: so it is like let the master set the things... I was looking up at `performSelectorOnMainThread` but there seems to be no way to get back any value (need to get back a `BOOL` value)

Comment: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...)` coupled with a `__block` variable lets you get values back, but it's probably a bad idea. Just use the properly-atomic shared boolean instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a subclass, you could store your state in variables in the object, then access these variables from any thread; provided of course these operations do not call methods defined by UIKit.